# What powers a comet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, comets

I know that a comet is a ball of ice, and I have tried the NASA page.

http://spaceplace.nasa.gov/dr-marc-solar-system/en/#/review/dr-marc-solar-system/comet-power.html

but they swerve around the question without answering it. It explains that a comet's tail always points towards the sun and what a comet is but not much else. Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "powering" a comet?

Comment: What powers a reolving planet?

Comment: If you understand the answer to @N.S.JOHN 's comment, that alone will get you the answer to your question.

Comment: Are you asking about the comet's tail or the comet's motion?

Comment: popular sciences answers link, think of kinetic energy: half square the speed times the mass gives you the KE in the appropriate units

Answer (score 2):

The motion of a comet can be understood in terms of a couple of principles.

First - Inertia. Newton's first law states that

> an object will remain at rest or in uniform straight line motion unless acted upon by an external force

In other words - assuming that "something" had given a comet a velocity, it will keep going *unless something changes that*. And there *is* something...

Second - gravity. As the comet flies through space, it will feel a weak pull of gravity from the Sun (the same force that keeps Earth moving around the Sun - except that Earth is very big, so we feel a much stronger force.). That force is directed along the line between the comet and the center of the Sun, and it gets bigger as you get closer. The equation is

$$F = \frac{G M_{sun}M_{comet}}{r^2}$$

Where $G$ is the Gravitational Constant ($6.67\cdot 10^{-11}\frac{m^3}{kg s^2}$), $M_{sun} = 1.99\cdot 10^{30} kg$ and $r$ is the distance between the two. I borrowed a [picture from wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Cometorbit.png) and modified it a little bit to show this more clearly:

[image]

The green arrows (which I added) represent the force of gravity on the comet. As it gets closer, you can see that the force gets stronger (arrow gets longer - not to scale). You may also be able to see that initially the force points partially *along* the direction of the comet: that means that the speed of the comet will increase; there is also a component of the force *perpendicular* to the path of the comet, which will *bend* the trajectory.

At the closest point to the sun, the *perihelion*, the force is entirely perpendicular to the trajectory: all that happens is that the comet is changing direction, but it's neither speeding up nor slowing down. Once it's past that point, it will start to decelerate as there appears a component of the force of gravity that points in the opposite direction to the velocity.